# How to configure Deployment Center configuration in ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, github-actions, azure-rm-template

I created a `Function App` through `GitHub Action` workflow and an `ARM Template` from `Azure`. It is a `CI/CD` workflow.

To deploy the `Function App` directly, I go to `Deployment Center` manually connect to GitHub. Then get the `Publish Profile` settings, and update the `GitHub` secret.

The manual process works! But if it is part of the `ARM Template`, the workflow fails.

[image]

I see a section in the `ARM Template` like below:

```
{
                    "type": "sourcecontrols",
                    "name": "web",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
                    "properties": {
                        "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoUrl')]",
                        "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
                        "IsManualIntegration": false,
                        "deploymentRollbackEnabled": false,
                        "isMercurial": false,
                        "isGitHubAction": true,
                        "gitHubActionConfiguration": {
                            "generateWorkflowFile": false,
                            "workflowSettings": {
                                "appType": "functionapp",
                                "publishType": "code",
                                "os": "linux",
                                "runtimeStack": "dotnet",
                                "workflowApiVersion": "2020-12-01",
                                "slotName": "production",
                                "variables": {
                                    "runtimeVersion": "7.0.x"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('name'))]"
                    ]
                }
```

But the above generates the error:

```
ERROR: ***"status":"Failed","error":***"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/f24b12b1-d887-4938-8c49-ce56acded667/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/azure-function-api","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[***"code":"NotFound","target":"/subscriptions/f24b12b1-d887-4938-8c49-ce56acded667/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/azure-function-api","message":"***\r\n  \"Code\": \"NotFound\",\r\n  \"Message\": \"Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub.\",\r\n  \"Target\": null,\r\n  \"Details\": [\r\n    ***\r\n      \"Message\": \"Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub.\"\r\n    ***,\r\n    ***\r\n      \"Code\": \"NotFound\"\r\n    ***,\r\n    ***\r\n      \"ErrorEntity\": ***\r\n        \"ExtendedCode\": \"51004\",\r\n        \"MessageTemplate\": \"Cannot find ***0*** with name ***1***.\",\r\n        \"Parameters\": [\r\n          \"SourceControlToken\",\r\n          \"GitHub\"\r\n        ],\r\n        \"Code\": \"NotFound\",\r\n        \"Message\": \"Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub.\"\r\n      ***\r\n    ***\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Innererror\": null\r\n***"***]***
```

What configuration that I need to have so I can pass the above error?

Instead of the manual step, are there `ARM Template` commands to get the `GitHub` repository name, branch and copy the secret to the `GitHub Settings\Secrets & Variables`  as `Repository secrets`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below ARM Template and added my repository URL that contains the Function and Branch in the source control parameter section of the template and tried deploying it, The Function Trigger got deployed successfully, Refer below:-

ARM template reference [**Link**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/function-app-dedicated-github-deploy/azuredeploy.json)

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "appName": {
            "defaultValue": "[concat('funtionapp-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the function app that you wish to create."
            }
        },
        "sku": {
            "defaultValue": "S1",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The pricing tier for the hosting plan."
            }
        },
        "workerSize": {
            "defaultValue": "0",
            "allowedValues": [
                "0",
                "1",
                "2"
            ],
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The instance size of the hosting plan (small, medium, or large)."
            }
        },
        "storageAccountType": {
            "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard_LRS",
                "Standard_GRS",
                "Standard_ZRS",
                "Premium_LRS"
            ],
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Storage Account type"
            }
        },
        "repoURL": {
            "defaultValue": "https://github.com/username/FunctionApp25",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The URL for the GitHub repository that contains the project to deploy."
            }
        },
        "branch": {
            "defaultValue": "master",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The branch of the GitHub repository to use."
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "functionAppName": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "hostingPlanName": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '-plan')]",
        "storageAccountName": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), 'functions')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
            },
            "kind": "Storage"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
                "numberOfWorkers": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "siteConfig": {
                    "alwaysOn": true,
                    "cors": {
                        "allowedOrigins": [
                            "*"
                        ]
                    },
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';')]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "sourcecontrols",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
                    "name": "web",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",
                        "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
                        "IsManualIntegration": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

You can check your Function deployment logs here and see if any settings needs to be changed, or any issue that is stopping the deployment from source control via github actions.

[image]

***Function Trigger got deployed from my github repository successfully like below:-***

**Added CORS setting like below:-**

[image]

[image]

In-order to deploy ARM template via Portal, Use the method below:-

Select Custom Deployment in Azure Portal > Build your own template in the editor> Add the ARM template above and deploy, Make sure you replace the repo_urrl and branch with yours in parameter:-

[image]

[image]

Click on Save, Select Resource Group > Review + Create > And the Function app with Trigger will be deployed:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I have "IsManualIntegration": true, I get the error ```Operation not supported: ManualIntegration does not support GitHubAction.```. If I have that value as false, I get the error ```Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub.```. My GitHubAction login to the Azure with a Service Principal which has contributor role. It can create all the resources that I want except connecting to the GitHub. If I run it manually to connect which I can. That manual process may be using my admin AD account that I use to login to Azure.

Comment: Do you a have solution to fix the error ```Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub.```?

Comment: For this you need to download Publish Profile from Your Azure Function app Overview page and add it as a secret in the Github repository > settings > Secrets > Actions and then add that variable in the Github action workflow for the workflow to work

Comment: Refer this github action workflow script here-https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/FunctionApp/windows-dotnet-functionapp-on-azure.yml and samples here- https://github.com/Azure/functions-action

Comment: I have to manually add the GitHub information on the ```Deployment Center``` page and then ```Download Publish Profile. I don't think you had to follow that step. My ARM template is generated from Azure and is almost like you. But you don't get the error message, but my script does. Is this due to I use ```Service Principal```?

Comment: Yes, It might be because of your service principal. As I don't get any error

Comment: Is there any documentation on using ```Servive Principal``` when creating ```source controls``` resources and what configuration need to be followed?