# Linux Function App in Azure portal won't start because it keeps looking for a directory in /home/site/wwwroot/

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-linux

I've been trying to get my Linux Function App running, but I've been stuck with this error now:

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.FunctionMetadataLoader: The file '/home/site/wwwroot/MyVsProjectName' was not found.

I can see all my project dlls and assets in /home/site/wwwroot/ yet this error keeps claiming that there should be a folder or file with my project name there?

My project is running using dotnet 6 isolated.

Any ideas why this FunctionMetadataLoader is looking for this file/folder? I checked similar Windows apps that I've deployed and they all have files directly in wwwroot.

This app is running within a Linux OS, I1 tier asp. And it release from CICD in Azure DevOps Zip Deploy.

Here is part of my arm template for the Function App.

```
"resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('appServiceName'), '-deployment','-', uniqueString(guid('any')))]",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('appServiceResourceGroup')]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
              "name": "[parameters('appServiceName')]",
              "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
              "location": "[parameters('location')]",
              "kind": "functionapp,linux",
              "tags": {
                "environment": "[parameters('environmentTag')]",
                "monitor": "[parameters('monitorTag')]",
                "owner": "[parameters('ownerTag')]",
                "workload": "[parameters('workloadTag')]",
                "serviceLine": "[parameters('serviceLineTag')]",
                "system": "[parameters('systemTag')]",
                "initiatingEpic": "[parameters('initiatingEpicTag')]",
                "dr": "[parameters('drTag')]",
                "notes": "[parameters('notesTag')]"
              },
              "identity": {
                "type": "UserAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                  "[resourceId(parameters('appServiceResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/',parameters('managedIdentityName'))]": {}
                }
              },
              "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('appServiceName')]",
                "httpsOnly": true,
                "reserved": true,
                "isXenon": false,
                "hyperV": false,
                "siteConfig": {
                  "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
                  "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
                  "ftpsState": "Disabled",
                  "http20Enabled": true,
                  "netFrameworkVersion": "v6.0",
                  "linuxFxVersion": "DOTNET-ISOLATED|6.0",
                  "appSettings": [
                    {
                      "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                      "value": "[reference(variables('appInsightsResourceId'), variables('appInsightsApiVersion'), '2016-03-01').instrumentationKey]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
                      "value": "[reference(variables('appInsightsResourceId'), variables('appInsightsApiVersion'), '2016-03-01').ConnectionString]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                      "value": "~2"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                      "value": "~4"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                      "value": "dotnet-isolated"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                      "value": "[parameters('storageAccountConnection')]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostId",
                      "slotSetting": false,
                      "value": ""
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
                      "slotSetting": false,
                      "value": "0"
                    }
                  ],
                  "connectionStrings": [],
                  "alwaysOn": true
                },
                "keyVaultReferenceIdentity": "[resourceId(parameters('appServiceResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/',parameters('managedIdentityName'))]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId(parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms',parameters('appServicePlanName'))]",
                "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('appServiceEnvironmentName')]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Project File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Warmup" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer">
      <TreatAsUsed>true</TreatAsUsed>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore" Version="2.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I tried updating WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1. And verified that wwwroot is empty after the release and I'm still getting the exact same error.

Comment: To anyone else who ever gets this error make sure your:  
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
is pointing to the correct architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

win-x64 needs to be linux-x64 if you're running a Linux Function App

Answer (score 0):

I tried deploying **`.Net 6.0 Isolated Function`** with Function App  via ARM template in Azure DevOps and it ran successfully, Refer below:-

*My ARM template code using source control parameter referred to my github Function code repository:-*

**functionapp.json**

You can try this ARM Template for testing.

Below ARM template reference from my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76729939/how-to-configure-deployment-center-configuration-in-arm-template/76736985#76736985) Refer my answer for more clarity on deploying Function app and Trigger with ARM template.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "appName": {
            "defaultValue": "[concat('funtionapp-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the function app that you wish to create."
            }
        },
        "sku": {
            "defaultValue": "S1",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The pricing tier for the hosting plan."
            }
        },
        "workerSize": {
            "defaultValue": "0",
            "allowedValues": [
                "0",
                "1",
                "2"
            ],
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The instance size of the hosting plan (small, medium, or large)."
            }
        },
        "storageAccountType": {
            "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard_LRS",
                "Standard_GRS",
                "Standard_ZRS",
                "Premium_LRS"
            ],
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Storage Account type"
            }
        },
        "repoURL": {
            "defaultValue": "https://github.com/sid24desai/FunctionApp49",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The URL for the GitHub repository that contains the project to deploy."
            }
        },
        "branch": {
            "defaultValue": "master",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The branch of the GitHub repository to use."
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "functionAppName": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "hostingPlanName": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '-plan')]",
        "storageAccountName": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), 'functions')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
            },
            "kind": "Storage"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
                "numberOfWorkers": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "siteConfig": {
                    "alwaysOn": true,
                    "cors": {
                        "allowedOrigins": [
                            "*"
                        ]
                    },
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~v4"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';')]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "sourcecontrols",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
                    "name": "web",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",
                        "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
                        "IsManualIntegration": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**My Azure Devops repository:-**

[image]

**My Build yaml pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'xxx subscription(xxxxd6-b4fd-e2xxxx)'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxxxxxxx2a7'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'valleyrg103'
    location: 'Australia East'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/functionapp.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Make sure you add this **`https://portal.azure.com`** in the CORS setting like below:-

[image]

**Function app with .net 6.0 Isolated Function got deployed and is running successfully refer below:-**

[image]

**Same Deployment with Release pipeline using ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope task :-**

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I opened a question in the Microsoft Questions section:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1392830/linux-function-app-does-not-start-with-website-run