# Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime when retrieving Azure Functions function app keys

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Have been trawling the internet for a while now and still haven't had much success in resolving this issue.

Deploying an Azure Function App through ARM template / Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline.
The deployment is completing with success however, any attempts to retrieve a list of function app keys leaves the webpage in a constant loading state.
Attempting to retrieve the key using the Azure CLi also returns a Bad Request response.
Looking at the Activity Log within the Azure Portal for the function app displays a Failed status on List Function host keys.

Full Error Message:

```
{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime."}}],"Innererror":null}
```

I have...

- checked the AzureWebJobsStorage config value is correct
- re-deployed function app with a new name, results in the same error
- re-deployed storage account and function app, results in the same error
- deleted storage account and function app, and redeployed the following day, results in the same error
- checked function app with and without function code, results in the same error
- checked the storage account settings, set to public access with no vnet configuration

To add to this, a number of additional function apps were deployed alongside this one but all the others are operating as expected. This function app was previously working and one day it stopped...

Function Extension Version ~4
Function Runtime dotnet

ARM Template: https://github.com/NZLorenzo04/azure-functionapp-template/blob/main/template.json

I'm thinking its an isolated issue, not sure what has caused this or how to resolve it. Looking to the great minds of Stack Overflow for support as i'm at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

Refer the ARM template from my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77291754/linux-function-app-in-azure-portal-wont-start-because-it-keeps-looking-for-a-di/77301005?noredirect=1#comment136294708_77301005) and to deploy the Function app via Azure DevOps yaml pipeline.

**My Azure Repository:-**

[image]

***My Complete ARM template:-
You can use this ARM template for testing:-***

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "appName": {
            "defaultValue": "[concat('funtionapp-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the function app that you wish to create."
            }
        },
        "sku": {
            "defaultValue": "S1",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The pricing tier for the hosting plan."
            }
        },
        "workerSize": {
            "defaultValue": "0",
            "allowedValues": [
                "0",
                "1",
                "2"
            ],
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The instance size of the hosting plan (small, medium, or large)."
            }
        },
        "storageAccountType": {
            "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard_LRS",
                "Standard_GRS",
                "Standard_ZRS",
                "Premium_LRS"
            ],
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Storage Account type"
            }
        },
        "repoURL": {
            "defaultValue": "https://github.com/sid24desai/FunctionApp49",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The URL for the GitHub repository that contains the project to deploy."
            }
        },
        "branch": {
            "defaultValue": "master",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The branch of the GitHub repository to use."
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "functionAppName": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "hostingPlanName": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '-plan')]",
        "storageAccountName": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), 'functions')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
            },
            "kind": "Storage"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
                "numberOfWorkers": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "siteConfig": {
                    "alwaysOn": true,
                    "cors": {
                        "allowedOrigins": [
                            "*"
                        ]
                    },
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~v4"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';')]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "sourcecontrols",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
                    "name": "web",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",
                        "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
                        "IsManualIntegration": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Added the CORS setting to allow `https://portal.azure.com` to run the Function Trigger from the Portal:-**

[image]

[image]

**Retrieved Function Key with the command below:-**

```bash
az functionapp keys list -g valleyrg103 -n funtionapp-pfau2zquvlcbw --query functionKeys.default
```

[image]